# Find duplicate row get only the older one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query that will give me those rows that have the field "username" duplicated:

```
SELECT id, jos_users.username, email, password, lastvisitDate 
FROM jos_users
INNER JOIN (SELECT username 
            FROM jos_users
            GROUP BY username HAVING count(id) > 1) dup 
           ON jos_users.username = dup.username;
```

I need to get those that have the lastvisitDate lower.

For example:

```
id  |  username  |  email  |  password  |      lastvisitDate      |
1   |  mylogin   |         |            |   2014-10-15 16:42:42   |
2   |  mylogin   |         |            |   2014-10-16 16:42:42   |
```

As you can see, the row with id=1 have the lowest lastvisitDate. How could I put this sentence on the query?
I want this because I'll peform a delete query using this select to delete duplicated rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id, jos_users.username, email, password, lastvisitDate
  FROM jos_users
 INNER JOIN (SELECT username
               FROM jos_users jb
              where jb.lastvisitDate =
                    (select min(jb1.lastvisitDate)
                       from jos_users jb1
                      where jb1.username = jb.username)
              GROUP BY username
             HAVING count(id) > 1) dup
    ON jos_users.username = dup.username;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write this as:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.email, u.password, u.lastvisitDate 
FROM jos_users u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM jos_users WHERE username = u.username GROUP BY username HAVING count(id) > 1)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM jos_users WHERE username = u.username GROUP BY username HAVING min(lastvisitDate) = u.lastvisitDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get minimum last visit date and do deletion

```
DELETE J FROM jobusers J
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT username, MIN(lastvisitDate)  as lastVisitDate
            FROM job_users
            GROUP BY username HAVING count(id) > 1 
)T
ON J.username = T.username
AND J.lastvisitDate = T.lastVisitDate
```